# HTML force the order of reading of VoiceOver

Tags: jquery, html, voiceover

i have tried with **tabindex** but it didn't work

is there a way to change the elements reading order without use JS swap code?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the order of your divs in your HTML code and then place them with flexbox's `order` property. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/order

The parent must have `display: flex` for it to work tho.

It's not the cleanest solution but that's a no-js one that should solve your problem.

Comment: with this solution i need CSS again all elements

Comment: Yes you do. But there is not so much work as you would imagine.
However, as i said it **is** pretty dirty but i know of no faster trick. (You could go for absolute positionning but that would be awfully longer to do and harder to maintain...)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into `aria-flowto` ?
https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-flowto

I haven't used it personally, but I'm pretty sure it's meant to define flow order of accessible applications.

Here's an example from the W3 link:

```
<h1 aria-flowto="main">The Daily Planet</h1>

<h2> Weather</h2>

<div id="weather" title="Weather" aria-flowto="sports">
    <p> The weather will be what it will be, if you want a forecast look out your window and have a guess. That's what the pros do!
    </p>
</div>

<h2> Election results</h2>

<div id="main" title="Election Results" aria-flowto="weather">
    <p> Whoever you vote for government wins. ANOK 1984</p>
</div>

<h2>Sports</h2>

<div id="sports" title="Sports">
    <p>Today there will be lots of goals scored, tennis played and footballs kicked.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: as mentioned in w3 article VoiceOver does not support it. Thanks anyway